# select_fields in rails how to store value instead of name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

how do i display the name of the room category and then store the id of it instead of the name
i have tried using the below statement

```
  = f.select :room_category_id, RoomCategory.all.pluck('name'), {},                  class: "form-control"
```

then i replaced it too the below statement , names get displayed but i cant stroe the value

```
  = f.select :room_category_id, RoomCategory.all.pluck('name'), {},                  class: "form-control"
```

can i use this in the modal instead, any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
= f.select :room_category_id, RoomCategory.collect{|p| [p.name, p.id]}, {},class: "form-control"
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: @edrichrocha @HardikUpadhyay Have you tried this solution ? `RoomCategory.collect` should throw you `undefined method collect' for #<Class...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= f.select :room_category_id, RoomCategory.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id]}
```

Comment: @edrichrocha If this solution worked for you, then you should accept it as answer.